# MYSQL - Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql

Well im having problems at executing this procedure and dont know how to fix it, thats all at all.

```
delimiter $$
    create procedure Ex_XII(data_partidaTre date,data_chegadaTre date,horario_partidaTre time,horario_chegadaTre time,distanciaTre varchar(200),
        id_CidOri_fk int,
        id_CidDes_fk int,
        id_Oni_fk int)

            begin
                DECLARE valor double;
                    if((select situacaoPol from Poltrona where Poltrona.id_Oni_fk=id_Oni_fk)='LIVRE')then
                        if(id_CidOri_fk != id_CidDes_fk)then
                            if(data_chegadaTre>=data_partidaTre)then
                                if(distanciaTre>0 and distanciaTre<50)then
                                    set valor = 30;
                                 insert into Trecho_Viagem values(null,data_partidaTre,data_chegadaTre,horario_partidaTre ,horario_chegadaTre ,distanciaTre,
                                                                        valor,
                                                                        id_CidOri_fk ,
                                                                        id_CidDes_fk ,
                                                                        id_Oni_fk ); 
                                else
                                    if(distanciaTre>=50 and distanciaTre<200)then
                                        set valor = 50; 
                                    else                                    
                                        set valor = 100;
                                    end if;
                                end if;                              
                            else
                                select 'Isto não é uma máquina do tempo';
                            end if;
                        else
                            select 'Você já está nesta cidade';
                        end if;
                    else
                        select'Existem poltronas ocupadas';
                    end if;
            end;
$$ delimiter ;

call Ex_XII('2000/12/12','2000/12/17','12:12:12','12:12:12','51',1,1,1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the statement below does not return more than one row -->

```
if((select situacaoPol from Poltrona where Poltrona.id_Oni_fk=id_Oni_fk)='LIVRE')then
...
```

Comment: thanks, i actually could do it by changing it to: if((select idPol from Poltrona where 'Ocupada')is null)then

Comment: Good to know! Did it solve the problem...that line of code?

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to do it,
changing the first "IF" to
if((select idPol from Poltrona where 'Ocupada')is null)then